# What new fractional brownian motion (fBm) simulation methods have emerged since 2010?

Tags: brownian-motion, simulation

I want to describe new methods for simulating fBm, as in the work of Coerjolly and Dieker, but new methods are not very easy to find.

Answer (score 0):

A recent paper (2021), with many pointers to the literature, is [ɛ-Strong Simulation of Fractional Brownian Motion and Related Stochastic Differential Equations](https://pubsonline.informs.org/doi/abs/10.1287/moor.2020.1078).